# the end of the I/O operation is notified to the system by an interrupt.how much system time do the mentioned operations occupy?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, interrupt, dma

Suppose the calculation time of a process is 200 cpu cycles. Meanwhile, the I/O operation is in progress for another process through dma, and after 100 cpu cycles, the end of the I/O operation is notified to the system by an interrupt. If we assume that the execution time of isr is 10 cpu cycles, how much system time do the mentioned operations occupy?

I am not sure of my answer but this is my solution.

The total execution time of the process is equal to the sum of cpu time = 200,I/O time = 100 and ISR time = 10. So the process takes 310 cycles.